# Dynamic, multiple string config for an app

Tags: android

I need your help with changing config in my app. What I have right now is strings.xml file, which holds different values i.e. city_name. Also I have different build configuration, so there is a lot of different looking apps I can build using same codebase, just each one of them has its own values directory, with unique strings.xml.

What I want to achieve now is, for each app I want to have multiple city_name attributes like for "App A", strings.xml in values directory, I want to have city_name_xyz, city_name_abc. For "App B", strings in values directory, will contain city_name_123, city_name_mno etc.

So, within the code I will obtain that "_xyz" or "_mno" suffix, but the thing is I dont know how to access my resources with dynamic name. Do not know where to start looking for an answers, so hopefully you can help me.

Best,
Radek

Answer (score 0):

You can use flavors for this - then you have different strings.xml files in the different flavors

Comment: can't do it - I need to switch between strings from within the app.